(MS Outlook for Mac; PST files) Is it possible to use (not import) a PST that was created by MS Outlook for Windows and is stored on my NAS?
I have PST files that were created and used by MS Outlook for Window; the PSTs are stored on my NAS. My Mac connects to my NAS and can access files there.
I would like use (read/write) those PSTs from my Mac using MS Outlook for Mac. (The PST would be open by one and only one Outlook instance at a time.)
Can I open (not import) such a PST from my Mac using MS Outlook for Mac and, if so, how?
TiA!

My understanding is that you need to import a pst. Alternatively open PSTs with ,for example, PST Bridge from https://www.arrowbit.com

Do you know if you can open (not import) PST files with Microsoft Outlook for Windows? If that's the case, it's possible Outlook for Mac somehow supports it. If it's not, I'm pretty certain Outlook for Mac can't either.

Ah! A friend forwarded https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/managing-pst-folders-in-outlook-for-mac/14439942-f733-4419-9b8f-8b65e10b0564 by the Great Diane Poremsky! It seems Outlook for Mac does not support PSTs at all. Sigh…
